# Android error when referring to XML variable in Java code

Tags: java, android, xml, variables

I am getting an error when referring to an XML variable in java code. Please help.

**My XML CODE**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    >

<LinearLayout

   android:id="@+id/llayout1"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   >
<TextView  
    android:id="@+id/tv"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 


    />    
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**My Java Code**

```
package com.motivational.wallpapers;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.util.Log;


public class wallpaper_activity extends Activity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
        Log.v("hello","tv value : " +tv);
        tv.setText(" There are many ways of doing things");
        Log.d("hello","tv value : " +tv);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

    }
}
```

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a common mistake and Julien's answer should fix the problem. In general I always place setContenView immediately after super.onCreate.

Comment: When you post a question saying that you "got an error" when you did something, it's always helpful to say what the error was.

Answer (score 4):

You should call setContentView before you call findViewById. Otherwise, since the XML won't have been loaded when you call findViewById, there is no way it can find the id.